# Node.js - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

Tags: node.js, express

Received `undefined throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);`
In my node-express app I'm stuck here solutions are most welcome

```
  const fs = require("fs");
    const text = "File ";
    
    fs.writeFile("node-message.txt", text)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("File Created");
      })
    
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("File not created");
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just require your module with promises as mentioned below code...

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const text = "File ";

fs.writeFile("node-message.txt", text)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("File Created");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("File not created");
  });
```